# viewDidAppear not called

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, viewdidappear

I have added tabbarcontroller, setViewControllers used for providing array of uiviewcontroller. viewDidLoad is called for this viewContollers but not viewDidAppear neither viewWillAppear.
the code I have written

```
- (void)loadView {
 printf("*********\n  loadView  \n********* ");
 UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
 contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 self.view = contentView;
 [contentView release];
 UITabBarController *tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
 tabbar.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
 piechartViewController *pr=[[piechartViewController alloc]init];
 pr.tagInAction=1;
 pr.title=@"Type";
 pr.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"trend.png"];
 pr.sDate=sDate;
 pr.nDate=nDate;
 piechartViewController *pr1=[[piechartViewController alloc]init];
 pr1.title=@"category";
 pr1.tagInAction=4;
 pr1.sDate=sDate;
 pr1.nDate=nDate;
 piechartViewController *pr2=[[piechartViewController alloc]init];
 pr2.title=@"paidWith";
 pr2.tagInAction=3;
 pr2.sDate=sDate;
 pr2.nDate=nDate;
 [tabbar setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pr,pr1,pr2,nil]];
 [self.view addSubview:tabbar.view ];
 [pr release];
 [pr1 release];
 [pr2 release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey, are you sure you want to work with `loadView` and not with `viewDidLoad` instead? 
And might you paste the code when you call this view controller?
Btw, "`self.view = contentView`"? Probably `[self.view addSubview:contentView]` sounds better, don't you think?